# Integral expression for $\left( r^2+(z \pm h)^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $ using complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

It can be shown using the theorem of residues that

> $$
> \left( r^2+(z+h)^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 
>  \operatorname{Im} 
> \int_0^\infty  \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{ f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\left( r^2 + (z-it)^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2}} \, ,
> $$
> with $r, z, h \in \mathbb{R}_+$.
> The kernel function is explicitly given by
> $$
> f(t) = \frac{t}{t^2+h^2} \, .
> $$

I was wondering whether an analogous integral formula can be written for
$
\left( r^2+(z-h)^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$ as well, always for $r,z,h \in \mathbb{R}_+$

Those integral representation are useful for my further mathematical analysis. Any help/hint/suggestion/idea are highly appreciated.

**Remark**:

It can be checked that the above integral representation applies for harmonic functions that satisfy Laplace equation.
Specifically, in cylindrical coordinates, both sides of the equation satisfy:
$$
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\cdot)\right) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} (\cdot) = 0 \, .
$$

Thank you,

Comment: What should prove?

Comment: How is $f(t)=t/(t^2+h^2)$ a kernel if its area in $(0,\infty)$ is unbounded?